# How do I connect this RGB controller?

Tags: motherboard, computer-building, led, rgb

I have a RGB controller that came with my PC case. It's SATA powered and has 6, 4-pin slots for fans and strips and 1, 4 pin at the top labeled MB.

I assume I can plug that in to the RGB Header on my MOBO to have my ASUS Aura software control it but I'm not sure if the orientation matters because the cable it came with has no indication on it.

I don't want to hurt my MOBO by plugging it in upside down. Should I just buy a higher quality GB controller like a CORSAIR iCue commander?

MOBO is ASUS TUF z790 with wifi. Case is made by RaijenTek.

This is the RGB controller:
[image: RGB controller]

[motherboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4yZm.jpg)
[4 pin cable with no polarity markings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM9tC.jpg)

Comment: Very difficult to see on your pictures but that 4-wire cable does seem to have a polarity marker. A little dot on the left cable very close to the connector. The dot (or stripe) on a cable usually indicates pin 1. Bigger question is if that RGB/FAN controller is compatible with Asus Aura

Comment: A quick look at the RaijenTek website leads me to believe that 4-pin cable is either a USB header or some sort of proprietary header. (There are no real standards for this. Every manufacturer invents his own custom shit.). Most likely NOT compatible with the RGB header on your motherboard. You will have to look up the manuals for that controller and check what is really going on.

Comment: @Tonny incredible catch there is a marking on one of the wires, I didn’t even notice. 

The top of the RGB controller says M/B RGB, so that’s why I thought it might go to the RGB header. If it’s a usb header is there somewhere else to plug it on my mobo to power it sans actually controlling it via Aura?

Comment: If it a USB header you should be able to plug it into an internal USB header on the motherboard (always check wiring, some motherboards DO NOT use the standard wiring). And in that case  the RaijenTek supplied software is used to control it.